# Defining the levels of nodes in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have a main DAG with 91 nodes and 176 edges. I would like to perform two tasks.

1. create a sub graph with all the nodes without in_going arcs
2. Define the level $lev_G(v)$ of $v$ in $G$ as follows:
   if a node has 0 in_going edge, then the level of the node is 1
   otherwise, the level is 2.

I successfully created the first step as follows:
G is the main graph. Min is a subgraph with nodes without incoming edge.

```
Min.add_nodes_from(n for n, in_degree in G.in_degree if in_degree ==0)
```

How do I achieve the second step in networkx?

Comment: Take a look at https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html.  This will help.

Comment: @Joel. Is it possible to re-assign the level using topological sort function()